# Remove % symbol from all the rows of a column of dataframe and convert the entire column values into float

Tags: python, string, pandas

A column of a dataframe named 'int.rate' has values like: 11.26%, 13.67%,..... where I need to remove the '%' symbol from all the rows of the column 'int.rate' and convert entire column values into float. I have already tried all other codes mentioned but even they threw errors so I need to know the exact code for this task. Please help! Below is the code that I tried:

```
x = data['int.rate'].str.split('%').astype(float)
```

which gives

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-52f9e2c36b19> in <module>()
          4 
          5 #Code starts here
    ----> 6 x = data['int.rate'].str.split('%').astype(float)
          7 print(x)
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        176                 else:
        177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
    --> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
        179         return wrapper
        180     return _deprecate_kwarg
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
       4999             # else, only a single dtype is given
       5000             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
    -> 5001                                          **kwargs)
       5002             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
       5003 
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
       3712 
       3713     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
    -> 3714         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
       3715 
       3716     def convert(self, **kwargs):
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
       3579 
       3580             kwargs['mgr'] = self
    -> 3581             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
       3582             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
       3583 
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
        573     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
        574         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
    --> 575                             **kwargs)
        576 
        577     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, klass, mgr, **kwargs)
        662 
        663                 # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
    --> 664                 values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
        665                 values = values.reshape(self.shape)
        666 
    /opt/greyatom/kernel-gateway/runtime-environments/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
        728 
        729     if copy:
    --> 730         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
        731     return arr.view(dtype)
        732 
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` just split `str`, when you need to remove characters at ends of `str` you might use `strip`. Try doing:

```
x = data['int.rate'].str.strip('%').astype(float)
```

in place of:

```
x = data['int.rate'].str.split('%').astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gave correct results. Will you please enlighten why strip worked and not split?

Comment: @KankshaDhakate: `str.split` produce `list`, for example `"50%".split("%")` result in `['50', '']`, whilst `str.strip` produce `str`, for example `"50%".strip("%")` result in `'50'`. When you request python to convert something to float then python *Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.* `list` is neither of these thus it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `split`, use `replace`. See the demo code:

```py
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', '10.2%'], ['nick', '15.7%'], ['juli', '14.67%']] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Interest']) 

# print dataframe. 
df 

Name    Interest
0   tom     10.2%
1   nick    15.7%
2   juli    14.67%

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   Name      3 non-null      object
 1   Interest  3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes


df['Interest'] = df['Interest'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)

df

   Name    Interest
0   tom     10.20
1   nick    15.70
2   juli    14.67

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   Name      3 non-null      object 
 1   Interest  3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```